# ¿Cómo invocar el autocompletado de Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode, autocompletar

Esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con programación, sino de accesibilidad al trabajar, y es: cómo ver el auto autocompletado de VSC.

Este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Con qué atajo se puede ver? Perdón por la pregunta, pero ya investigué y no encuentro nada.

Comment: Ctrl + Espacio muestra el IntelliSense, si vuelves a apretar Ctrl + Espacio Code te mostrará más información sobre el elemento.

Comment: @JesúsHagiwara Gracias 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La combinación Ctrl + Espacio muestra el Intellisense. Si apretas esa combinación una vez más teniendo la lista del IntelliSense desplegada, Code te mostrará más información sobre el elemento.

Comment: Lo publico como respuesta para que sea más fácil de encontrar para otras personas que tengan el mismo inconveniente (te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada y sea más fácil de ubicar).